# Mongodb generate row number with find query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents in mongo collection:

```
{name: "Test1", "date" : "2014-09-01"},
{name: "Test2", "date" : "2014-08-01"}
{name: "Test3", "date" : "2014-07-01"}
{name: "Test4", "date" : "2014-06-01"}
{name: "Test5", "date" : "2014-05-01"}
{name: "Test6", "date" : "2014-04-01"}
```

I am issuing an aggregate query on mongo (using java) to find the documents between particular dates. The output of the query looks like this:

```
{name : Test3},
{name : Test4}
```

In this output, I want to have a row_number which should start from 0 and should have unique value, like Oracle's rownum. Is it possible in mongo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try looking for $unwind operator in mongo Db.
Following link would help :
https://dandelaney.co/assigning-a-real-time-ranking-order-index-to-a-sorted-list-using-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework-1c072b2aa550
Once you have filtered the documents, apply the unwind operator to get the results and set rank. Hopefully below example will clarify the same.
We are basically creating an array first and then unwinding the array along with array index (which we use as rownum/rank)

```
[
{ "$match": { }},
{"$group": {"_id": { "statement.actor.mbox":"$statement.actor.mbox", "organisation":"$organisation"},"points": { "$sum": "$statement.result.extensions.resultExt:pointsEarned"},"coins": { "$sum": "$statement.result.extensions.resultExt:coinsEarned"}}},
{"$sort": { "points" : -1 }},
{"$group": {"_id": 1,"results": {"$push": {"id": "$_id", "points": "$points", "coins": "$coins"}} }},
{"$unwind": {"path": "$results", "includeArrayIndex": "rank"}},
  {"$project": {
    "id": "$results.id",
    "points": "$results.points",
    "coins": "$results.coins",
    "rank": { "$add": [ "$rank", 1 ] }
  }}

]
```